# Jupyter kernel is not linked to conda environment in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I know similar questions have been asked before but previous answers do not help.

The problem:

Although, I installed a kernel from an active conda environment, the conda environment uses the wrong python interpreter. I tried the following:

```
# 1. Activate my conda environment snowflakes
$ conda activate /opt/miniconda3/envs/snowflakes 

# 2. Install another kernel that is connected to snowflakes after env is activated 
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name snowflakes --display-name snowflakes_2 

# 3. Run jupyter-lab
$ jupyter-lab

# 4. Check path in jupyter notebook
sys.path

>>['/Users/user/Documents/Code/Python /PyCharm_Test',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

# 5. The path should look like this:

>> ['/Users/user/Documents/Code/Python /PyCharm_Test/src',
'/Users/user/Documents/Code/Python /PyCharm_Test',
'/opt/miniconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python310.zip',
'/opt/miniconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python3.10',
'/opt/miniconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
'/opt/miniconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

I tried to reinstall ipykernel and jupyter-lab several times. Further, I tried to install kernels in various forms and I tied to start jupyter-lab from anaconda navigator. All without help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
#1 install nb_conda_kernels in base environment and in conda environment of choice

#2 Run the following code in the activated conda environment 
$ conda install --channel=conda-forge nb_conda_kernels

#3 Open jupyter-lab
$ jupyter-lab
```

Before I created Kernels that were still linked to base python. Now, I have a kernel for all miniconda3 conda environments. I don't know what went wrong from the start but it works now.